# How does upsampling rare events affect the interpretation of logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, sampling, rare-events

The answer to this question can be found here [Does down-sampling change logistic regression coefficients?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67903/does-down-sampling-change-logistic-regression-coefficients)

I have a dataset of 50k positives and nearly 1M negatives.  Instead of taking a random sample to build a logistic regression I take all 50k positives and randomly sample 50k negatives.  How should I interpret the logistic regression coefficients of the upsampled version since that sample is not actually representative of my original population?

Here is a toy example where the sampling will generate two different regression coefficients

```
beta = rnorm(5)
X = matrix(rnorm(10000*5), nrow = 10000)
y = X%*%beta + rnorm(10000)
label = ifelse(y > 3, 1, 0)

X.pos = X[label == 1,]
X.neg = X[label == 0,][1:sum(label),]

summary(glm(c(label[label == 1], label[label == 0][1:sum(label)]) ~ .,
            data = as.data.frame(rbind(X.pos, X.neg)),
            family = binomial()))

Call:
glm(formula = c(label[label == 1], label[label == 0][1:sum(label)]) ~ 
    ., family = binomial(), data = as.data.frame(rbind(X.pos, 
    X.neg)))

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-3.10121  -0.22644   0.00143   0.33291   3.01340  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -3.4787     0.2639 -13.184  < 2e-16 ***
V1            0.8904     0.1163   7.657 1.91e-14 ***
V2           -0.2319     0.1105  -2.100   0.0357 *  
V3           -2.9831     0.2064 -14.456  < 2e-16 ***
V4            1.3729     0.1333  10.299  < 2e-16 ***
V5           -1.6344     0.1435 -11.387  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 1522.15  on 1097  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  544.67  on 1092  degrees of freedom
AIC: 556.67

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 7

summary(glm(label ~ .,
            data = as.data.frame(X),
            family = binomial()))

Call:
glm(formula = label ~ ., family = binomial(), data = as.data.frame(X))

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.5939  -0.1856  -0.0701  -0.0229   3.6145  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -5.60342    0.15260 -36.720  < 2e-16 ***
V1           0.67740    0.06001  11.287  < 2e-16 ***
V2          -0.27957    0.05780  -4.837 1.32e-06 ***
V3          -2.32995    0.08786 -26.520  < 2e-16 ***
V4           1.17757    0.06548  17.985  < 2e-16 ***
V5          -1.27162    0.06675 -19.052  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 4254.0  on 9999  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 2187.1  on 9994  degrees of freedom
AIC: 2199.1

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Odds ratios or coefficients for the covariates are estimated correctly but intercept is affected by the sampling scheme. So probability estimates are not valid at population level.

http://support.sas.com/kb/22/601.html

Comment: It is confusing to see why you would do something that discards data and makes things more difficult by hurting the intercept.

Comment: @FrankHarrell perhaps JCWong thinks that it is frequency which is important and not the absolute numbers of observations with respect to covariates and such...

Comment: To estimate model parameters you don't want to reduce the sample size.  Logistic regression works fine with a highly imbalanced $Y$ distribution.

Comment: @FrankHarrell I'm sure you know about Gary King's work ([among others](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/107574/36229)). Care to elaborate on why that rare events isn't an issue here? Or do you mean to use one of those methods instead of resampling?

Comment: This has been discussed elsewhere on the site.  Gary King's excellent work is not inconsistent with what I wrote.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Would you mind pointing us to some posts where that discussion has happened? I skimmed through Gary King's work and would appreciate an alternative perspective on the issue. Thank you.

Comment: I wouldn't find that useful unless you can point to a place in his excellent paper where he said you must do it that way.  When I read the paper I didn't see that.

Answer (score 0):

This is called [importance sampling](http://www.columbia.edu/~mh2078/MCS_Var_Red2.pdf).

Here's my wild guess based on intuition and gut feeling. Your positive was sampled at 20:1 rate to negative. So your logistic probability should be: $$y=\frac{e^{X\beta}}{20+e^{X\beta}}$$, where $X\beta$ is your logistic regression part.

This is in contrast to a standard binary logit
$$y=\frac{e^{X\beta}}{1+e^{X\beta}}$$