# Estimating the true frequency of rare events

Tags: rare-events

I have a dataset containing some hundreds of thousands of observations, out of which some small number contain an event of interest `x`. Let's say that my total dataset is large enough that I have a decent confidence in the overall frequency of `x`.

But what I'm really interested in is the frequency of `x` together with some other condition `y`, and the frequency of `y` in the dataset is much lower. The total number of observations of `y` doesn't give me enough data to make a confident prediction about how well it correlates with `x`, and the actual number of observations of `x+y` is often zero, even though the theoretical frequency of `x+y` must be something larger than zero.

So how can I estimate the true probability of `x+y`, given the overall frequency of `x` in the data set and the small-ish number of instances of `y` that I have?

**Edit**: I know that `x` and `y` are not independent, but at the outset I don't know anything about the nature of the relationship between them. The entire point of the exercise is to determine whether they have a positive or negative correlation.

Sorry, I know next to nothing about statistics and I don't know what the proper terminology is to describe this situation.

Comment: Does this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/107574/strategy-to-deal-with-rare-events-logistic-regression or this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134380/how-to-tell-the-probability-of-failure-if-there-were-no-failures help?

Comment: @Tim, it helps, especially https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/134385/185985 since Bayes' Theorem is about the only part of statistics that I *am* familiar with.

Comment: Would you say that it answers your question? If yes, we may close it as duplicate. If no, maybe you could make it more precise what does it not answer?

Comment: @Tim I'll look at it and return in a day or so if I have more questions.